# Presentation with a window instead of full-screen (that I can share over screen-sharing even when I have only one monitor)?

Tags: pdf-viewer, presentation

I've been looking for a presentation software for pdf slides,
whose presentation mode shows a resizable window instead of entering a full-screen mode.

That would be handy for giving a presentation over screen-sharing when I have only one monitor because I would be able to see the other windows on my monitor while giving the presentation.

Comment: So the folks watching your presentation are watching your monitor – or would the presentation go to a beamer or shared other monitor? In the latter case, and if you are not bound to PDF, you might be interested in taking a look at LibreOffice "presenter console", which then would handle the presentation on the "remote screen" – giving you the freedom to deal with "your" screen as you wish.